# Python - создание только необходимых атрибутов класса

Tags: python, классы, dict

Имеется словарь:

```
months = {"january": 1, "february": 2, "june": 3}
```

Неизвестно какие месяцы будут в словаре - я должен классу Service передать атрибуты "january" и "march"

```
class Service:
    def __init__(self, months):
        if months.get('january'): self.january = self.months['january']
        if months.get('march'): self.march = self.months['march']
        if months.get('february'): self.february = self.months['february']

service = Service()
```

В моем случае я получаю то, что хочу - если не имеется такого месяца в словаре то атрибут не будет создан, и будет проверять уже следующий. В итоге мне нужно чтоб обьект имел только атрибуты существующих месяцев. Есть альтернативный способ это сделать? Как мне кажется не самое лучшее решение

Comment: Непостоянные атрибуты — не очень хорошая идея. Вы уверены, что вам их нужно именно не создавать совсем, а не, например, выставить значение `None`?

Comment: Точно `self.months`, а не просто `months`? По коду months все-таки передается

Comment: @gil9red да вы правы,  просто код писал прям здесь

Comment: @andreymal  думал насчет этого. Если так сделать, то будет ли возможность потом создать словарь  s = json.dumps(service.__dict__) только с атрибутами которые не None. Так как этот метод берет все атрибуты, а моя конечная цель это конвертировать обьект в json

Comment: @ValekPotapov лично я бы в такой ситуации изобрёл бы какой-нибудь метод типа `to_json`, в котором проверял бы значения атрибутов на None и выводил бы только то, что нужно. Да, такой код выйдет длиннее и «тупее», но поятнее и проще в сопровождении, потому что не будет иметь граблей в виде не всегда существующих атрибутов (но не буду утверждать, что мой вариант единственно верный)

Comment: Если ничего не останется то так и сделаю либо поменяю архитектуру немного, но это слишком долгий и банальный вариант..

Answer (score 1):

Атрибуты класса хранятся в магическом поле `__dict__`, который является словарем, а т.к. параметр `months` тоже словарь, то это позволяет использовать метод словарей `update`:

```
class Service:
    def __init__(self, months):
        self.__dict__.update(months)


months = {"january": 1, "february": 2, "june": 3}
service = Service(months)
print(service.january)   # 1    
print(service.february)  # 2
print(service.june)      # 3
```

---

Фильтрация элементов:

```
class Service:
    def __init__(self, months):
        months = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] is not None, months.items()))
        self.__dict__.update(months)
```

Comment: дело в том, что мне нужно , чтобы обьект не имел атрибутов None, а также чтобы не взял в себя ВСЕ атрибуты словаря

Comment: Фильтрацию добавил. А по поводу того чтобы не брал все элементы... нафига такое условие? :)  Просто не передавайте ненужное. Если есть еще данные, пусть идут другим параметром. Или раз так нужно, передавайте в конструктор вторым параметром функцию, которая будет определять какой элемент словаря нужен в атрибутах :)

Comment: Вы сейчас фильтруете словарь который мы получаем на входе, но это словарь не будет иметь значений None вообще, его не нужно проверять. Словарь получаем только с атрибутами, которые существуют. В вашем случае класс обретет атрибуты не None, но и не те к примеру, которые хочет класс - например "june" как в моем примере, он просто не нужен.

Comment: Вариант с передачей функции можно попробовать

Comment: Суть в том чтобы обьект не имел значений None тех атрибутов которые он должен иметь, но которых не имеет входящий словарь, а чтобы он их просто не создавал